# With Blazor access a component from another when they are not parent/child

Tags: c#, razor, blazor-server-side, razor-pages

On a page there are 3 components :

- One Component1
- Two Component2

They are NOT parent/child but side by side. I'd like from `Component1` hide one or both `Component2` via some buttons not present in the code below

**Component1:**

```
public partial class Component1 : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public Component2 Component2A { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Component2 Component2B { get; set; }
}
```

**Component2**

```
public partial class Component2 : ComponentBase
{
    private bool IsVisible = false;

    public void ToggleVisibility(bool isVisible)
    {
        IsVisible = isVisible;
    }
}
```

In the page

```
<Component1 Component2A=rightComponent1 Component2B=component2B />

<Component2 @ref="component2A" />
<Component2 @ref="component2B" />
```

I get these errors :

```
The name 'component2A' does not exist in the current context
The name 'component2B' does not exist in the current context
```

Am I missed something ? I have to define `@ref="component2A"` and `@ref="component2A"` somewhere ?

**Update 1 based on "MrC aka Shaun Curtis".**
I'd like pass data (`MyModel`) to components. When I change a value in the value propagate to all components.

I do this :

**My Model**

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

**Page**

```
<CascadingValue Value=_context IsFixed>
    <Component1 ComponentA=this.ComponentAUid ComponentB=this.ComponentBUid />
    <Component2 Uid=this.ComponentAUid><div class="alert alert-danger m-2">Hello from component 1</div></Component2>
    <Component2 Uid=this.ComponentBUid><div class="alert alert-success m-2">Hello from component 2</div></Component2>
</CascadingValue>

@code {

    private XPageContext _context = new XPageContext(new MyModel { FirstName = "MyFirstName" });

    private Guid ComponentAUid = Guid.NewGuid();
    private Guid ComponentBUid = Guid.NewGuid();

}
```

**Record**

```
public record RegisteredComponent(Guid Uid, Func<bool, Task> Show, MyModel MyModel);
```

**Component2**

```
@if(_isVisible)
{
    @this.ChildContent
}

<EditForm Model="MyModel">
<InputText @bind-Value=MyModel.FirstName />
</EditForm>



@code {
    [Parameter] public Guid Uid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    [CascadingParameter] private XPageContext _context { get; set; } = default!;

    [Parameter] ublic RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public MyModel MyModel { get; set; }

    private bool _isVisible = false;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(_context);
        MyModel = _context._myModel;
        _context.Register(Uid, this.ToggleVisibilityAsync);
    }

    public Task ToggleVisibilityAsync(bool isVisible)
    {
        _isVisible = isVisible;
        // Called as this is not a UI event and therefore doesn't cause an automatic render
        StateHasChanged();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.DeRegister(Uid);
    }
}
```

In the `InputText`, I see the firstName value in the 2 `Component2` but when I change in one there no impact on the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't pass around component references: you have no control over their lifecycles and can easily have a reference to a "dead" component.

You need to create a shared comtext shared by all the components.  This solution may seem a litle complex, but it demonstrates the principles of complex inter component communications.  You can share a `Scoped` service, but this doesn't match the scope of a page.  Here I use a standard object and pass it down through a cascade.

The shared Context:

```cs
public class XPageContext
{
    private List<RegisteredComponent> _registeredComponents = new();

    public void Register(Guid uid, Func<bool, Task> show)
    {
        if (!_registeredComponents.Any(item => item.Uid == uid))
            _registeredComponents.Add(new RegisteredComponent(uid, show));
    }

    public void DeRegister(Guid uid)
    {
        var component = _registeredComponents.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Uid == uid);

        if(component != null)
            _registeredComponents.Remove(component);
    }

    public async Task ShowComponentAsync(Guid uid, bool show)
    {
        var component = _registeredComponents.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Uid == uid);

        if (component != null)
            await component.Show.Invoke(show);
    }
}

public record RegisteredComponent(Guid Uid, Func<bool, Task> Show);
```

**Component2**

```
@implements IDisposable

@if(_isVisible)
{
    @this.ChildContent
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public Guid Uid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    [CascadingParameter] private XPageContext _context { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    private bool _isVisible = false;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(_context);
        _context.Register(Uid, this.ToggleVisibilityAsync);
    }

    public Task ToggleVisibilityAsync(bool isVisible)
    {
        _isVisible = isVisible;
        // Called as this is not a UI event and therefore doesn't cause an automatic render
        StateHasChanged();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.DeRegister(Uid);
    }
}
```

**Component1**

```
<h3>Component1</h3>

<button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=this.ToggleComponentA>Toggle Component A</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.ToggleComponentB>Toggle Component B</button>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private XPageContext _context { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Guid ComponentA { get; set; }
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Guid ComponentB { get; set; }

    private bool _componentAState;
    private bool _componentBState;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(_context);
    }

    private async Task ToggleComponentA()
    {
        _componentAState = !_componentAState;
        await _context.ShowComponentAsync(ComponentA, _componentAState);
    }
 
    private async Task ToggleComponentB()
    {
        _componentBState = !_componentBState;
        await _context.ShowComponentAsync(ComponentB, _componentBState);
    }
}
```

**Index**

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<CascadingValue Value=_context IsFixed>
    <Component1 ComponentA=this.ComponentAUid ComponentB=this.ComponentBUid />
    <Component2 Uid=this.ComponentAUid><div class="alert alert-danger m-2">Hello from component 1</div></Component2>
    <Component2 Uid=this.ComponentBUid><div class="alert alert-success m-2">Hello from component 2</div></Component2>
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    private XPageContext _context = new();
    private Guid ComponentAUid = Guid.NewGuid();
    private Guid ComponentBUid = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```